# Java :How to connect to database using Jbutton taking user input data

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

In gui user enter username and password then click ok button.But the problem is i don't know how to connect with my Connector Class with ok button. And Give restriction to that button when user enter correct fields then connect to database.
Main Method

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui obj = new Gui();
        Connector conn = new Connector(obj.Setproperty());  
    }

}
```

Gui Class

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JButton ok;
    private JPanel p1,p2;

    Properties property;

    public Gui(){
        super("GUI");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        p2=new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel("User Name");
        t1 = new JTextField();
        label2 = new JLabel("Password");
        t2 = new JTextField();
        ok= new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(this);
        add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(label1);
        p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(label2);
        p1.add(t2);
        p2.add(ok);

        setSize(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        property = new Properties();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==ok){
        }

    }

    public Properties Setproperty(){

        property.setProperty("UNAME",t1.getText());
        property.setProperty("PWD",t2.getText());
        return property;
    }

}
```

Connector Class

```
public class Connector {
    Connection conn;
    Statement state;
    String username;
    String pass;
    String url; 

    public Connector(Properties p) {
        username = p.getProperty("UNAME");
        pass = p.getProperty("PWD");
        url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/world";
    }

    public boolean open() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass);
            state = conn.createStatement();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(conn==null){
            System.out.println("Connection is NULL or server not connected");
            return false;

        }

        System.out.println("Connection Successfull");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that `actionPerformed` is not being fired when you click "OK"?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the actionPerformed method to this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==ok){
        Properties prop = Setproperty();
        Connector c = new Connector(prop);
        c.open();
    }
}
```